# MFC app Assert fail at CRecentFileList::Add on Command line FileOpen

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, com, mfc

I'm using VS2010 and Windows 7, and my app is SDI shared DLL, upgraded from VC6. After installing my application, if the user double-clicks the registered file type, the application crashes at the MFC function:

```
void CRecentFileList::Add(LPCTSTR lpszPathName, LPCTSTR lpszAppID)
{
 // ...
#if (WINVER >= 0x0601)
// ...
#ifdef UNICODE
// ...
#endif
ENSURE(SUCCEEDED(hr));    // Crash here: "hr = 0x800401f0 CoInitialize has not been called."
```

This is called from the InitInstance() function:

```
// Parse command line for standard shell commands, DDE, file open
CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);

//CString str = cmdInfo.m_strFileName + '\n';
//MessageBox(NULL,str, "MyApp", MB_OK|MB_ICONWARNING);

// Dispatch commands specified on the command line
if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
    return FALSE;
```

The user's chosen file is correctly passed through (as I checked with the MessageBox).

The hr = 0x800401f0 seems to be a COM problem ([here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?threadid=483418)), but I'm not using COM or ATL. The assertion is the same as [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcmfcatl/thread/afafec8b-8e0d-4650-a548-c5753a35cba0), but from a different cause. The Germans had the same problem as me ([here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/visualcplusde/thread/7ef1affd-e611-4dc8-878a-c0a73f761225/)), but I can't understand the google translation ([here](http://translate.google.ie/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=de&tl=en&u=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/visualcplusde/thread/7ef1affd-e611-4dc8-878a-c0a73f761225/))!! I don't think it's a WINVER issue ([here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcmfcatl/thread/1f27fca0-da5b-4c2e-8e1f-0ae554c6f3b5)) and I don't want to parse my own stuff ([like this](http://www.visualcpp.org/?p=33)), just have the application open when a user double clicks a file.

Thanks for any help you can offer :)

Comment: The system might be using COM and ATL, even if you don't do that directly. The first link hints on initialization  being different for VC6 and VC10. I'd create a new application and compare the generated initialization code to the one you have. Bet there are some new calls!

Comment: There sure are Bo! But I tried that: I generated an empty MFC project, took the new/different code bits and applied them to my main app - no joy. I don't want to have to move a 20k line app to an empty MFC project because of this! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, I see. I have never gone directly from VC6 to VC10, but taken all the intermediate steps and noted that there were changes most of the time.

Comment: I held out as long as I could ;) Perhaps the solution is to move it all to a newly generated skeleton MFC app. I could use new features then too...Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment you inserted in your code contains the answer:

```
// Crash here: "hr = 0x800401f0 CoInitialize has not been called."
```

The `HRESULT` value is telling you that you need to call the [`CoInitialize` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678543.aspx) in order to initialize the COM library for your application's thread.

Of course, the message is a little bit outdated. As you'll see in the above-linked documentation, all new applications should call the [`CoInitializeEx` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms695279.aspx) instead. No worries, though: it does essentially the same thing as its older brother.

As the "Remarks" section of the documentation indicates:

> `CoInitializeEx` must be called at least once, and is usually called only once, for each thread that uses the COM library. [. . . ] You need to initialize the COM library on a thread before you call any of the library functions except `CoGetMalloc`, to get a pointer to the standard allocator, and the memory allocation functions. Otherwise, the COM function will return `CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED`.

**You say that you're not using COM, but this is incorrect.** You may not be using it explicitly, but Windows and the MFC framework are definitely using it "behind the scenes". All of the file type registration functions rely on COM. The skeleton code produced by the MFC project wizard in Visual Studio 2010 would have automatically inserted the appropriate COM registration code, but since you upgraded an existing project from VC++ 6, you appear to be missing this vital step.

In MFC, the [`AfxOleInit` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e91aseaz.aspx) also initializes COM for the current apartment of the calling app, just as the [`OleInitialize` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690134.aspx) does internally. Make sure that your overridden `InitInstance` function contains a call to one of these functions.

For example, in a fresh new MFC project created by the VS 2010 wizard, the `InitInstance` function looks something like this:

```
BOOL CTestApp::InitInstance()
{
    // InitCommonControlsEx() is required on Windows XP if an application
    // manifest specifies use of ComCtl32.dll version 6 or later to enable
    // visual styles.  Otherwise, any window creation will fail.
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
    // Set this to include all the common control classes you want to use
    // in your application.
    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

    CWinApp::InitInstance();

    // Initialize OLE libraries
    if (!AfxOleInit())                   // ** MAKE SURE THAT YOU CALL THIS!! **
    {
        AfxMessageBox(IDP_OLE_INIT_FAILED);
        return FALSE;
    }

    AfxEnableControlContainer();

    // . . . 
    // a bunch more boring initialization stuff...

    // The one and only window has been initialized, so show and update it
    pFrame->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    pFrame->UpdateWindow();
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Cody - that really helps. So just to be clear: in the InitInstance() add: CoInitializeEx(); followed by AfxOleInit(); I see that CoInitializeEx() needs to be balanced by a call to CoUninitialize() in an overridden ExitInstance(). Is this correct?

Comment: @Colin: No, you actually don't need to call both `CoInitializeEx` **and** `AfxOleInit`. The `AfxOleInit` function provided by MFC (AFX means the same thing as MFC for nonsensical technical reasons) actually wraps the call to `CoInitializeEx` for you, along with a handful of other initialization functions. I suspect that for whatever reason, your VC6 app wasn't calling that (maybe it didn't exist back then?). And yes, technically you should uninitialize COM when your application exits, but Windows will handle that for you anyway.

Comment: @Colin: I think someone suggested in the comments to compare the standard boilerplate code that VS2010 starts you off with in a new project with your existing code. It shouldn't be too hard, and it will likely address some of these tricky migration bugs.

Comment: Cody thanks for continuing to help. I had tried using code from a skeletal app already to no successs. I tried again with your code (CWinApp instead of CWinAppEx as I had before), but I get an ASSERT fail because my code tries to update the UI before m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW); has been called <sigh>. But that's my problem, not MFC I think. Thanks again!

Comment: @Colin: Hmm, yeah. I believe that `CWinAppEx` is part of the new MFC feature pack introduced with Visual Studio 2008. The project I created didn't use any of the fancy features like a ribbon control. And yes, it's strange that you should be updating your UI in the `InitInstance` function. UI work should be confined to the window class that is responsible for *displaying* that UI. You don't want to put that code in your *main application* class. Don't forget that MFC still encourages object-oriented programming, despite its occasional messiness! :-)

Comment: Fixed a CMyDoc ctor initialization and now working. The command line FileOpen command trickles down to the UI before m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW); is called - thank you so much for all your help!