# ProcessShellCommand throws "Access is denied"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, visual-studio-2017

Due the migration from Win7+VS2015 to Win10+VS2017 we face following issue in our old MFC tool:

> from afxwin.h: CWnd* m_pMainWnd; // main window (usually same
>   AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd)

```
CSingleDocTemplate* pDocTemplate;
pDocTemplate = new CSingleDocTemplate(
    IDR_MAINFRAME,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CIFX_LogViewDoc),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMainFrame),       // main SDI frame window
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CIFX_LogViewView));
AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);   

// Parse command line for standard shell commands, DDE, file open
CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);

// Dispatch commands specified on the command line
if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo)) // -> "Access is denied"
    return FALSE;

// The one and only window has been initialized, so show and update it.
m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();

return TRUE;
```

I also tried to call ShowWindow()+UpdateWindow() before parsing the command line as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41188727/384556 but it does't work:

```
Exception thrown at 0x58198F2E (mfc140d.dll) in A.exe: 0xC0000005: Access 
violation reading location 0x00000020. occurred -> in m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: An Access Violation near address 0 usually means you are accessing a class member via a NULL pointer. So clearly `m_pMainWnd` is likely NULL when you are not expecting it to be. You need to fix that.

Comment: Put a break point at the beginning of `CYourApp::InitInstance()` (`CYourApp` being the name of your `CWinApp` derived class), see if `this` is `NULL`; if it's alread `NULL` here then I have no special advice, you need to debug it. If it is not `NULL` then step through your code and see when `this` is becoming `NULL`. It must become `NULL` somewhere between the break point and the call to `ProcessShellCommand`.

Comment: The error is deeper in your application. Most of the MFC work happens in `ProcessShellCommand` and if it returns with success it should have created a main window and `m_pMainWnd` sall not be `NULL` on the line trying the show it `ShowWindow`. So you need to start debug, start with `ProcessShellCommand` and `CSingleDocTemplate`. You could also search for `LoadFrame()` in the MFC source and set a breakpoint

Comment: This an  "Access violation", NOT "Access is denied" There is huge difference. The first is bad memory access and the other is about security. Look the error text.

Comment: @A.A The Access violation error comes from the suggested adaptation (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41188727/384556) and not from the original issue!